# What is the difference between web3.js and web3-light.js?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

everyone!
What is the difference between web3.js and web3-light.js files from the [web3.js library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web3.js` contains the [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) module while `web3-light.js` does not.

**Long answer:**

`web3.js` is [open-source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/gulpfile.js) project, so lets see what's inside. `Web3` use Gulp build system to produce different  versions of library. The code responsible for `light` flavour looks like this:

```
gulp.task('light', ['clean'], function () {
    return browserify(browserifyOptions)
        .require('./' + src + '.js', {expose: 'web3'})
        .ignore('bignumber.js')
        .require('./lib/utils/browser-bn.js', {expose: 'bignumber.js'}) // fake bignumber.js
        .add('./' + src + '.js')
        .bundle()
});
```

> [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) is JavaScript library for arbitrary-precision decimal and non-decimal
>   arithmetic.